# Задать задний фон в разных браузерах

Tags: css

как сделать подобное:

```
-webkit-background-size:cover;
```

В браузерах Мозила и Опера, пробовал так:

```
-o-background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
```

Но не помогло, заранее спасибо.

Comment: не страдайте ерундой, определите лучше класс в зависимости от броузера

Comment: @shurik, броузер?

@oOKomarOo, добавьте к перечисленным Вами свойствам `background-size`. А для других браузеров лучше либо выбрать другой метод отображения, либо делать фоновое изображение тегом `<img/>` и масштабировать его скриптом.

Comment: Должно поддерживаться http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

Comment: `background-size` поддерживается уже давно и везде безо всяких вендорных префиксов https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: Вопрос с 12 года, когда уже все поменялось по 100 раз, Дух такой Дух...

Answer (score 1):

вот это у меня работает уже давно на всех браузерах

```
background: url(images/sun2.png) no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: 100%; /* Firefox 3.6+ */
-webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
-o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.6+ */
background-size: 100%; /* Современные браузеры */
```

Comment: `100%` - это не `cover`